# doParallel does not work while doMC does

Tags: r, parallel-processing

Sometimes doParallel does not work and does not give me any error. I am not sure how to state this problem, since I cannot provide a reproducible example.

```
library(doParallel)
cl <- makeForkCluster(32) 
registerDoParallel(cl)

library("rwrfhydro")
pathUsgs <- "someAddress"
fileUsgs <- list.files(pathUsgs, pattern = glob2rx("stn*"), full.names = TRUE)
huc4 <- fileUsgs[-grep('daily', fileUsgs)]
SliceUsgs <- function (huc4){
     load(huc4)
     # do some other analysis and write some netcdf files
}
plyr::llply(as.list(huc4), SliceUsgs, .parallel= TRUE)
stopCluster(cl)
```

If I use doMC instead of doParallel, everything is fine but using doParallel no file is written. Any idea or suggestion?

Comment: Do you have this issue only on fork clusters or on other type clusters as well?  Have you checked if your workers are spawned and actually doing something?  I have had issues with fork clusters seemingly unstable. Sometimes workers are there but almost idle, and the process takes an eternity to complete.  Multicore and MPI seem to work better.  As a side note: do you really have 32 cores?

Comment: the `makeCluster` functions (eg `makeForkCluster`) are in package **parallel**, not **doParallel**.... though it appears parallel is required by doParallel, so this may be irrelevant

Comment: what is your `sessionInfo()`? Forks are only available on Unix systems. Are you running Windows?

Comment: I am running this on a supercomputer. And I have access to 32 cores, it is working fine if I change doParallel to doMC. But I am very new and I am not sure what do you mean other type of cluster (rather than fork cluster).

Comment: Ott was right about process taking eternity to complete. I tested with doMC and I had the same problem.